# Is there any way to use physical device for testing server sided apps? [Android]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

I just upgraded to Android Studio 3.x.x and what I  came to know is that I  can't run emulator on my rig, as it is outdated.
So I just wanted to know is there any way i can use the 10.0.2.2 thing on my **physical device?**
because the emulator gets stuck on boot screen i waited for more than an hour but it didn't showed anything.

---

searched through stack also didn't find such topic, if there exist any post like this please redirect me to it.

Comment: You can always plug in a  physical device, turn on the developer options and USB debugging on your phone and debug on the device.  You can also use wifi, but that's a little insecure and requires your network to be set up right.

Comment: I guess _"the 10.0.2.2 thing"_ wasn't descriptive enough for people to understand what you mean. So, you want to connect to a "server" on your computer from the real Android device? I think this worked for me by making the Android phone a Wi-Fi hotspot and connecting the computer to it. Then the devices are in the same network and you'll just connect to the computer's IP address from the Android app.

Answer (score 1):

You can plug in your physical device with USB Debugging turned on and then run the app from your android studio or command line.

**[Read More here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device)**